# How do I configure WCF client to use XElement and not XmlDocument?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, xelement

I have an **ASMX webservice** that returns `XElement` - (not an .svc WCF service)

When consuming the service in Silverlight the client that is generated uses `XElement` as I want.

However in C# .NET 3.5 WCF 'Service Reference' it generates this property using `XmlDocument`.

In C# .NET 4 WCF 'Service Reference' it also generates this property using `XmlDocument`. So it doesn't seem to be a .NET 4 thing - but a Silverlight thing.

How can I configure the WCF client to use `XElement` also in the standard 3.5 framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the service from an `ASMX` web service to `SVC` WCF service. Wasn't much work at all. Just one more thing I never got round to doing.

This then without changing anything else allowed the .NET 3.5 client to use `XElement` instead of `XmlElement`.

Looks like Silverlight is just smart enough to always use XElement - come to think of it `XmlDocument` probably doesn't even exist in the Silverlight framework in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I Find/Replace XMLElement with XElement in my proxy class. Dirty trick... but it works.

Comment: at least someone finally admits to the same problem! thanks. oh and welcome to stackoverflow :-) i don't get this problem anymore fortunately now i'm done with ASMX