# How do I use XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd, xsd.exe

Seriously I'm confused. I have an .XSD that is made from a class so that I can pass to a webservice. It got it over to the webservice as an XMLSchema object and now I need to make it into a class so that I can make objects out of it on the webservice side. I know that XSD.exe is the answer but I'll be darned if I can puzzle out exactly how to implement this thing. I need it to do this conversion at run time so I need to put the code for it into my project and all the references I've seen to using XSD.exe talk about calling it from the command line. My .XSD is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Field">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

In my project this is living in an XMLSchema object. How do I turn it into a class?

-Thank You so much for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing webservices in .NET, you do not need to resort to fiddling with XSD.

There is a wsdl.exe tool if you use the 1st gen webservices stack from .NET, aka .ASMX webservices. There is the svcutil.exe tool that you would use if you are relying on WCF.

Those things generate client-side proxy code, which provide classes that allow webservices clients to invoke web services.  Implicitly they rely on XSD, but you do not need to use the xsd.exe tool directly, nor do you need to deal directly with .xsd files.

Comment: But how does this work with Custom Classes that I create. For instance I have a webservice that executes a dynamic LINQ query with a Select Statement. Because the schema of the returned object is different than the one requested (Because it has a different number of columns) it can't serialize. My idea to get around that was to build a custom class, dynamically, on the client side as determined by the fields they request in their query and send that class with request to the dynamic LINQ webservice so that when the data is returned it can serialize into the schema I created back on the client.

Comment: There are well-trod paths to delivering XML data that has a flexible schema. On one end of the spectrum, there is the XML Document/XML Element approach, where the service can return any well-formed XML. At the other end is the approach with firm, fixed XSD-defined schema for all data items. To balance between those two extremes, you can specify optional elements or wildcards via `<xsd:any>`. This relies on the eXtensibility of XML (the X part). I'd recommend that you look into the WSDL-first design approach, and think twice before proceeding with generating classes on the client dynamically.

Comment: Do you have any good references for learning more about this. I'm learning as I type with this whole idea as I work on a project for work. The end result of which is to allow users to Choose tables and Fields from those tables, as well as enter "Where" clauses and send that to a webservice to conduct Dynamic LINQ queries and return the data back to their client. It's this whole serializing across the webservice that's really killing me and I'm having difficulty finding a good solid source to learn from.

Comment: You know, the more you describe what you are doing, the more I think you ought to go to an XElement (wide open) format.  The result of a LINQ query can be, of course, *anything*.  Any shape, any schema, fully dynamic. For that you should return XElement from the web service. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904477/how-do-i-configure-wcf-client-to-use-xelement-and-not-xmldocument

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 2.0, then simply use "Add Web Reference" and point to the WSDL file of the service. If you are using any later version, then use "Add Service Reference".

Both of these will create the classes you need to communicate with the service, and no need to play with XSD.EXE or even WSDL.EXE.